# create a dictionary with duplicate elements from two unequal length of lists

Tags: python, scripting, automation

```
list1=['abc','pqr','xyz','abc','xyz'] -> student names

list2=[50,30,20] -> marks
```

1. list1 and list2 can be of unequal length
2. list1 can have duplicate names
3. need to make dictionary out of these two lists
4. If there are no marks for students, need to put 0 for them

Desired output:

```
 d = {'abc':50,'pqr':30,'xyz':20,'abc':0,'xyz':0}
```

I tried zip, padding None, but nothing worked, not getting duplicate elements in dictionary.

Can someone please help me on how to solve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you need to be clearer about what you are trying to do. As has been pointed out in the answers, a dictionary can't contain duplicate values. So you need to be very clear about what you want to *do* with this data. Why do you think you need a dictionary? *If you could use a dictionary, which value(s) would you want to be returned when you asked for, say, `d['abc']`?* What are you going to do next with the data? What *exact* way of accessing the data do you actually need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do what you want to do. Dictionaries are key: value pairs in which the keys must be unique, because the lookup happens in a hash table. You can't therefore have duplicate keys.

If you need to store multiple values against a single key you could store a collection (list or even another dict) against the key rather than a single value, but your problem would then be identifying which student 'abc' got 50 marks and which one got 0.